# How to get the data from DialogFragment in ChildViewHolder?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-datepicker

I have expandable recycler view. 
In this recycler view I have ChildViewHolder, where below method is called:

```
public void showDatePickerDialog() {
    DatePickerFragment datePickerFragment= new DatePickerFragment();
    SelectionActivity activity = (SelectionActivity) mContext;
    datePickerFragment.show(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
```

My DatePickerFragment:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    public DatePickerFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return datePickerDialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        TimePickerFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
    }
}
```

In DatePickerFragment I also calling TimePickerFragment right after DatePickerFragment closing.

My question is: how can I get date information (also time information) in my ChildViewHolder?

Comment: You can create your own listener. Set listener in your DatePickerFragment and handle the response in your ChildViewHolder. I don't know if this mechanism really the best, but why not try

Comment: @PavliukR you were right, thank you! It seems this is the best approach. I've added the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create own listener in DatePikerFragment:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

    private DateDialogFragmentListener dateDialogFragmentListener;

    public void setDateDialogFragmentListener(DateDialogFragmentListener dateDialogFragmentListener) {
        this.dateDialogFragmentListener = dateDialogFragmentListener;
    }

    public interface DateDialogFragmentListener{
        void onDateSelected(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);

        return datePickerDialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        dateDialogFragmentListener.onDateSelected(year, month, dayOfMonth);
        TimePickerFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "df");
    }
}
```

And setting this listener in ChildViewHolder:

```
public void showDatePickerDialog() {
        DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.setDateDialogFragmentListener(new DatePickerFragment.DateDialogFragmentListener(){

            @Override
            public void onDateSelected(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                timeTextView.setText(year + "/" + month + "/" + dayOfMonth);
            }
        });

         newFragment.show(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }
```